# How to Check for Class in body_class() in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Within Wordpress header.php, I have

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```

How do check to see if a specific class exists, and then load markup as a result?
For ex.

```
<body class"home logged-in">

<?php if $class == 'home' ?>
    <div class="home"></div>
<? else : ?>
    <div class="internal-page"></div>
<? endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you really, really need to use different markup based on the `body_class` classes, then use [`get_body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class)

```
$classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('home',$classes)) {
    // your markup
} else {
    // some other markup
}
```

But there are probably better ways to do this, like @Rob's suggestion of [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). Those map pretty closely to the classes used by `body_class`.

Comment: I have tried your method of grabbing the body class with 'get_body_class();', but when itterating through the array and echoing the content, it spits out ALL the class tags, EXCEPT the one I manually added with 'body_class($class);'. Am I doing something wrong? I can see my class in the body tag, but 'get_body_class();' doesn't have it contained in there...

Comment: @KerynGill : it sounds like you a have a different issue than in the OP. You should probably open or own question and provide your code for us to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `body_class` with a filter `add_filter('body_class', function ...)` however, I think you are taking the wrong approach. Why not just use css for what you need? For example, `.home>div { /* home styles */ }`

Or you can load a different stylesheet

```
add_filter('body_class', function($classes) {
    if (in_array('home', $classes)) {
        wp_enqueue_style('home');
    }
    return $classes;
});
```

Comment: I want to take this approach vs. adding stylesheet with specific classes so that I can for ex load a particular partial only for the homepage, or load another php snippet or mark-up based on another class.

Comment: Then i suggest using [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as I created pages using different templates but a custom sub-menu needed to be the same on each pages.

I tried this one first what is failed

`<body <?php body_class( 'extra-class' ); ?>>`

The extra classes was added to the body tag but when I run the error log then it was not in the classes array. So I was sure it was added later to the body tag.

This solution worked for me:

`functions.php`

`$GLOBALS['extraBodyClass'] = '';`

In the template file

`<?php $GLOBALS['extraBodyClass'] = 'extra-class' ?>` - very first line in the template file

`<body <?php body_class( $GLOBALS['extraBodyClass'] ); ?>>` - after the template name declaration

In the `header.php` file

```
$classes = get_body_class();
if($GLOBALS['extraBodyClass']){
   $classes[] = $GLOBALS['extraBodyClass'];
}
```

Comment: Your answer is about adding a class to the body tag, while this question is about finding out if a specific class was added to the body tag.

Comment: If you read his answer given to the `best answer` he said that adding the class with `<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>` did not work. It was my problem as well and the method I added worked for me.

Comment: +1 I don't know why this answer was downvoted. It provides an alternative approach and was actually the perfect solution in my case with a similar issue to the OP.