# Check if a body has class "paged-"

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to find if the body class basically has part of a class as Im currently using is_paged() in an if-statement and that is working. Of course as the paged pages goes, it's "paged-1, paged-2" etc.

Anyone have an idea to see a way to create an if-statement that involves:

If bodyclass has "paged-", or "paged-numerical_value" then do something.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about CSS classes or PHP objects?

Comment: Why do you need you code to run?  You could add a new [body_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) filter that runs after all the others, and do something if the value passed to it contains a class matching that pattern.  Or you could do it in javascript.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: php object.  Body is generating the paged-# when on a paged page, i'll be adding a custom tag for tracking on those pages that are paged so would need to do it on the template and not js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033888/how-to-check-for-class-in-body-class-in-wordpress it's a linked question (to the right) so likely easy to have searched for..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
// Get the body classes as array
$classes = get_body_class();

// For exact maych try this
if (in_array('paged-1', $classes)) {
    // ...
}

// For partial match try this
$match = FALSE;
foreach($classes as $string) {
    if (strpos($string, 'paged-') !== FALSE) {
        $match = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}

if($match) {
    // ...
}
```

Read about [get_body_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class) function on `Codex`.

Answer (score 0):

You should continue to use the is_paged code and not worry about the body class since it's generated by the same logic.

In template:

```
<?php
if(is_paged()) {
    // do something
}
?>
```